# Protractor install issues. SSL error, Behind Corp firewall

Tags: node.js

I have set http and https proxy, I am behind a corporate firewall, I am trying to install protractor and I am running into the below error, please help in solving this.

```
C:\nodejs>npm install protractor
npm ERR! Error: 7156:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:795:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at SlabBuffer.use (tls.js:235:18)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:455:29)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:369:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24)
npm ERR!     at flow (_stream_readable.js:611:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:643:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\n
pm-cli.js" "install" "protractor"
npm ERR! cwd C:\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\nodejs>
```